# how to change all the hostnames reported by hostname --all-fqdns?

Tags: networking, hostname

Running `hostname -A` reports two host names:  an incorrect one that doesn't even resolve to my server and a correct one.

```
$ hostname -A
notmyhostname.notmydomain.com  myhostname.mydomain.com
```

The incorrect one is messing up other tools like xauth.   I `grep -r`'ed /etc to try to find where this value is stored, but I can't find it.

Where are these stored and how can I fix the first hostname value?

Answer (score 2):

The extra hostname comes from a DNS .in-addr.arpa IP address lookup (often called 'reverse DNS', that maps IP addresses to hostnames).  Or perhaps `/etc/hosts`.

From `man hostname`:

> -A, --all-fqdns
>
> Displays all FQDNs of the machine. This  option  enumerates  all
>   configured  network  addresses  on all configured network interfaces, and translates them to DNS domain names.  Addresses  that cannot be translated (i.e. because they do not have an appropriate reverse IP entry) are skipped. Note that different addresses may  resolve  to the same name, therefore the output may contain duplicate entries. Do not make any assumptions about  the  order of the output.

Note especially the phrase **This  option  enumerates  all
configured  network  addresses  on all configured network interfaces**

So, to find out where `notmyhostname.notmydomain.com` is coming from, generate a list of all IP addresses on all interfaces, and do a reverse-DNS lookup on each of them:

```
ip addr | awk '/inet/ {gsub(/\/.*/,"") ; print $2}' | xargs -n 1 host
```

This will do lookups for ipv6 as well as ipv4 addresses.  If you want only ipv4, add a space after 'inet', e.g.

```
awk '/inet / ...' ...
```

BTW, most likely it's your ISP or hosting provider (or their upstream) or whoever owns the `.in-addr.arpa` or `.ip6.arpa` domain for your IP subnet.  They will have added a reverse-DNS entry for your IP.